# Como mostrar solo un rango de valoresen el eje Y de highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

estoy haciendo unas graficas en highcharts con doble eje Y, y me muestra los valores de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que pasa es que como los valores del eje Y (lado derecho) tiene diferencias minimas, que estan entre 100 y 99, y no se nota las diferencias de las graficas.

habra alguna manera de especificar que solo me tome desde 99 a 100 y no desde 0 a 120 como sale en la imagen?

este es mi codigo

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
            width: 480,
            height:295,
            backgroundColor: '#423C37',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'GRAFICA',
            style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                }
        },/*
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },*/
        xAxis: [{
            categories: [<?php for ($i=1; $i <=$c ; $i++) { 
                echo "'week ".$i."',";
            } ?>]
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value} und',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'R',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'DISPO',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}%',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            enabled: true,
        },
        /*legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
        },*/
        series: [{
            name: 'Volumen',
            color: '#4572A7',
            dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [
            <?php for ($i=0; $i <$c ; $i++) {  ?>
            {
                y: <?php echo $valor_grafico[$i].","; ?>                    
                color: <?php if ($valor_grafico[$i]>=99.9) { echo "'#2aa714',"; }
                if ($valor_grafico[$i]<99.9 && $valor_grafico[$i]>=99.5) { echo "'#e5e507',"; }
                if ($valor_grafico[$i]<99.5 && $valor_grafico[$i]>=99.0) {echo "'#FA7D08',"; }
                if ($valor_grafico[$i]<99.0) {echo "'#e61b06',"; } ?>
            },
            <?php } ?> 
            ],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperatura',
            color: '#4572A7',
            dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
            type: 'spline',
            data: <?php echo "[".$line."],"; ?>
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'und'
            }
        }]
    });
});


    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta con `max` y `min` asi:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
            width: 480,
            height:295,
            backgroundColor: '#423C37'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'GRAFICA',
            style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                }
        },/*
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },*/
        xAxis: [
            {categories:['week1', 'week2','week3','week4','week5','week6']}]
        ,
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value} und',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'R',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'DISPO',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}%',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true,
            max: 100,
            min: 99,
            startOnTick: false
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            enabled: true,
        },            
        series: [{
            name: 'Volumen',
            color: '#4572A7',
            dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [
            99.54,99.59,99.37,99.4,99.59,99.63
            ],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperatura',
            color: '#4572A7',
            dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
            type: 'spline',
            data: [6.31,6.41,5.48,5.78,6.44,6.66],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'und'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css">

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: alan, me esta pasando lo mismo que en lo que tu mandaste, el highcharts no respeta el maximo y minimo que se establece, x ejemplo tu pusiste tu minimo 99, y te puso que tu minimo es 98.8. en mi caso yo estoy especificando para la parte de "R", pongo mi maximo es 10 y mi minimo es 0, y me marca desde 0 hasta 12. habra alguna manera de que me limite a lo que yo especifique en el MAX y MIN?

Comment: Agrega `startOnTick: false`, ya edite mi respuesta.